# Frames with labels

Tags: framed

Is there a LaTeX package somewhere that would let me create frames with a label inside the line, e.g.:

```
############################# some text ######
#                                            #
#                                            #
#                                            #
#                                            #
##############################################
```

?

Comment: check tcolorbox

Answer (score 3):

Hello¡ If you are new in SE, maybe you are not familiarized with packages documentation. As Ulrike Fischer commented, you can create frames with a label inside the line with `tcolorbox` package. You can see this short example I made:

[image]

generated by

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % It generates text
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
    colback=teal!20!white,
    colframe=teal!25!black,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top center={xshift = 1.5cm, yshift = -2mm},
    boxed title style={colback=red!20!white, colframe=white},
    title=#2,#1
}


\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[]{Some text}
    \lipsum[1] % Text to let you see the display
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A package with 525 pages of documentation *is* intimidating...

Comment: That's why I answered your question, I hope my answer was useful to you @MichelCharpentier

Comment: As documentation goes, that for `tcolorbox` is among the best organized and presented. Use the index for individual things relevant to your project and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I've been able to get to what I want:

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    fonttitle=\itshape,
    attach boxed title to top right={xshift = -1cm, yshift = -\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={frame hidden,size=fbox},
    title=#2,#1
}
```

The only drawback is that the background has to be white, but I can live with that.

Thanks for the help.